nginx dual virtual host setup fails
I am attempting to setup a 2 virtual host system with nginx. This is my config:
#user  nobody;
worker_processes 1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events
{
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http
{
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    #gzip  on;

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.first.domain;

        location /
        {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #Internal port of first application
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.second.domain;

        location /
        {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000; # Internal port of second application
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

}



On ports 3000 and 4000, Node.JS applications are running and can be accessed properly via localhost:3000 and localhost:4000.
Navigating to both my.first.domain and my.second.domain bring me to localhost:3000, when my.second.domain should bring me to localhost:4000.

A quick glance and your config looks correct enough... is it definitely under sites-enabled and you've reloaded nginx ?

may be you are having typing mistakes in second block for server_name
